# How to install proj4 in ubuntu? make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop. geodjango

Tags: django, postgresql, gis, postgis, geodjango

I'm following the geodjango docs [proj4 section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/gis/install/geolibs/#proj4) , I have installed `proj-7.0.1.tar.gz` and `proj-datumgrid-1.8.tar.gz` , and untar them as in the docs mentioned , but when i try to run `make` command after directory .`/configure` it returns

> make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

Is there something I have missed? Maybe I have used a wrong version?

Thank you!

Comment: `./configure` is not a directory.  Did you execute it?  What happened?

Comment: when i run ./configure it runs and works , but make command not work , and say make is not found

Comment: "make is not found" and "no makefile found" are quite different messages.   Assuming it is the latter, the job of ./configure is to make the makefile.  If it didn't, something must have gone wrong.  Look more carefully at the output.

Comment: No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop. its the error sorry , misspelled

Comment: I mean look more carefully at the output of ./configure.  It is hard to believe it exited without creating the makefile, but also without giving any error messages.